# How to make scrollView 'bounce' on tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

For example, on the iOS 7/8 lock screen, if you tap rather than drag it to the right, it will have a slight bounce effect. How can I detect the tap gesture (and not have it be confused with the dragging) and recreate a similarly subtle 'bounce' effect? Can anybody share a code example (swift/obj-c) ?

I think this is a great way to show the user that something should be dragged rather than tapped and it doesn't require reading any small indicators.

Comment: Do you want to add the same effect in your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `tap gesture` to your View like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Can be done using `UIView's` `animateWithDuration` method in `handleTap:` method

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
  __block CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         frame.origin.x += 20.0f;
                         scrollView.frame = frame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         scrollView.frame = frame;
                     }];
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't use the dampening animation and also does not allow user to take control of the scrollView when they desire. They have to wait for the animation to end. This is an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(recognizeYourTap:)];
[self.yourView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; 


- (void) recognizeYourTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)ges
{
    //DO your Animation stuff what prince mentioned

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map the tap gesture with an `UITapGestureRecognize` on the view. But you have to implement some of the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods to work with both gesture recognizers.

The 'bounce' effect is made possible with the `UIView` animateWithDuration or with the `CoreAnimation` Framework